# Deceptive site ahead

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, subdomain, cpanel

I have the next error: "Deceptive site ahead". My app is separate in frontend with Angular 8 and backend  with Laravel 5.8. The issue is when I deploy the backend to a subdomain (services), Google Chrome shows me that error. What's wrong?

I've done the same with another easy Laravel project and it's fine, but I don't know why it happens in this project.

I hope someone helps me and sorry for my English.

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Did you solve your issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with your code. Google has blacklisted/marked as unsafe your site for some reason which can harm users. If it is not done by you then you may have some script or file on your server which google has found and thinks it is unsafe. After clearing your files you may try to submit for review.

Check here more detailed information: https://www.malcare.com/blog/deceptive-site-ahead/