# Deceptive site ahead | Laravel app deploy on cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting, production

Here is the screenshot of this.
[image]

Few monts ago I deployed my this laravel app in cpanel. But Now when I'm accessing the site it shows me this message... I think it is hacked or malwared added in the app.
Can anyone tells
**what are security steps?** should I have to follow for deploying the project in cpanel securely...?

> How can I protect my app from attackers in cpanel?

What I missed on basic think in my app was `APP_DEBUG` was `false` I have to set this to `true`.
Except this is `App_Debug`:

- Is there any security should I follow...
- Or should I have to move shared hosting to dedicating hosting..?

Comment: please take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106122/deceptive-site-ahead

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your hosting or your APP_DEBUG setting. In fact **never set APP_DEBUG to true on a live website this can leak all your environment variables including database credentials to the world**

Here's an [explanation from the google site](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/security/social-engineering):

> Social engineering is content that tricks visitors into doing something dangerous, such as revealing confidential information or downloading software. If Google detects that your website contains social engineering content, the Chrome browser may display a "Deceptive site ahead" warning when visitors view your site. You can check if any pages on your site are suspected of containing social engineering attacks by visiting the Security Issues report.

In your case it may be because either (as you said) the website was hacked and this content injected in it or (less likely) there is content you added to the site that Google is interpreting as misleading (either because it is or because it looks like it is even though it is not).

The remedy here is explained by the above linked site (wont include the entire text just a gist but do check the entire Google site):

1. Check in with Search Console
2. Remove deceptive content
3. Check the third-party resources included in your site
4. [Request a review](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/request_review)

If your page has been hacked then you should probably just delete everything, change your passwords (all of them) reset the app key and re-deploy it. Also contact your shared hosting provider to tell them what happened in case they need to be aware of any vulnerabilities or credential leaks.

Comment: Yes I did `request review` and deleted the file as the google reviewers show me. Now how much time I have to wait...? after deleting the file I did request submit..

Comment: It might take a while. Give it a few days

Comment: I do not even see any warnings on the site, or while accessing the site. It's only google search console showing 1 security error. I do not know how to fix it?